# How can I separate from and to dates from dates array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, which has only one month dates.

```
$dates =array (
            '2018-10-15',
            '2018-10-16',
            '2018-10-17',
            '2018-10-13',
            '2018-10-19',
            '2018-10-10',
            '2018-10-11',
            '2018-10-12',
            '2018-10-22',
            '2018-10-23',
            '2018-10-29',

        );
```

And script below

```
usort($dates,function($a,$b){
            return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
        });
        $consecutive_added_set = [];
        $consecutive_array = [];
        $temp = [];
        $temp[] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates[0]));
        for($i=1;$i<count($dates);++$i){
            if(strtotime($dates[$i]) - strtotime($dates[$i - 1]) === 86400){ // 1 day gap(86400 seconds)
                $temp[] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates[$i]));
                $consecutive_added_set[$dates[$i-1]] = true;
                $consecutive_added_set[$dates[$i]] = true;
            }else{
                if(count($temp) > 1){
                    $consecutive_array[] = $temp;   
                }
                $temp = [];
                $temp[] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates[$i]));
            }
        }
        if(count($temp) > 1){ //  the last consecutiveness match of dates as well(corner case)
            $consecutive_array[] = $temp;
        }
        $conseq[] = []; // reset the array structure 
        $conseq['consecutive'] = $consecutive_array;
        $conseq['consecutive_count'] = count($consecutive_array);
        $conseq['non_consecutive'] = [];
        foreach($dates as $current_date){
            if(!isset($consecutive_added_set[$current_date])){ // skip all dates which were d for consecutiveness
                $conseq['non_consecutive'][] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($current_date));
            }
        }
```

Which is sorting and separating consecutive and non-consective dates. Currently in consecutive array it is showing all dates by group. But I just would like to show `from` and `to` dates. Here is output of above script

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [consecutive] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-10-10
                    [1] => 2018-10-11
                    [2] => 2018-10-12
                    [3] => 2018-10-13
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-10-15
                    [1] => 2018-10-16
                    [2] => 2018-10-17
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-10-22
                    [1] => 2018-10-23
                )

        )

    [consecutive_count] => 3
    [non_consecutive] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-10-19
            [1] => 2018-10-29
        )

)
```

**My desired output**

```
[consecutive] => Array
    (
        ['dates1'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2018-10-10
                [3] => 2018-10-13
            )

        ['dates2'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2018-10-15
                [2] => 2018-10-17
            )

        ['dates3'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2018-10-22
                [1] => 2018-10-23
            )

    )
```

I have tried a lot to do it.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Why has it not worked for you?

Comment: Please use `var_export()` when showing us the sample data. It makes it so much easier for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `min` and `max` on the timestamps maybe???

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround would be to get the first and last item in the array.

```
    $consecutive_array = array_map(function($e){
        if(!is_array($e)){ 
            return $e;
        }
        $last = end($e);
        return [reset($e), $last];
    }, $consecutive_array);
```

Or as suggested in the comments use `min()` `max()`  functions.

```
    $consecutive_array = array_map(function($e){
        if(!is_array($e)){ 
            return $e;
        }
        return [min($e), max($e)];
    }, $consecutive_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** don't rely on `strtodate` of a day being exactly 86400 seconds less than the `strtodate` of the next day - depending on the locale of the server, there will be daylight saving, which can mess this up!

In cases like this, I tend to compare `strtodate('+1 day',$timestampOfDay1)` to `strtodate($timestampOfDay2)` - this will include daylight saving.

Here's how I would do it:

```
//the dates
$dates =array (
            '2018-10-15',
            '2018-10-16',
            '2018-10-17',
            '2018-10-13',
            '2018-10-19',
            '2018-10-10',
            '2018-10-11',
            '2018-10-12',
            '2018-10-22',
            '2018-10-23',
            '2018-10-29',

        );

//call the function
$result = getConsecutive($dates);

//output
var_dump($result);

function getConsecutive($dates) {
    sort($dates);

    $result = [
        'consecutive' => [],
        'consecutive_count'=>0,
        'non_consecutive' => []
    ];

    $currentStart = null;
    $currentTimestamp = null;

    for ($i=0; $i<count($dates); $i++) {
        $timestamp = strtotime($dates[$i]);

        if ($currentStart == null) {
            //first timestamp - set it as start & current
            $currentStart = $timestamp;
            $currentTimestamp = $timestamp;
        } else if (strtotime('+1 day',$currentTimestamp) == $timestamp) {
            //consecutive - keep waiting for a non-consecutive
            $currentTimestamp = $timestamp;
        } else {
            if ($currentTimestamp == $currentStart) {
                //we just got one
                $result['non_consecutive'][] = date('Y-m-d',$currentTimestamp);
            } else {
                //we just got more then one, so they were consecutive
                $result['consecutive']['dates'.(count($result['consecutive'])+1)] = [
                    date('Y-m-d',$currentStart),
                    date('Y-m-d',$currentTimestamp)
                ];
            }
            $currentStart = $timestamp;
            $currentTimestamp = $timestamp;
        }
    }
    //process the last timestamp
    if ($currentTimestamp == $currentStart) {
        //we just got one
        $result['non_consecutive'][] = date('Y-m-d',$currentTimestamp);
    } else {
        //we just got more then one, so they were consecutive
        $result['consecutive']['dates'.(count($result['consecutive'])+1)] = [
            date('Y-m-d',$currentStart),
            date('Y-m-d',$currentTimestamp)
        ];
    }
    $result['consecutive_count'] = count($result['consecutive']);

    return $result;
}
```